# Open Xml Excel set cell format to be Percentage

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have c# code that programmatically inserts cells in spreadsheet. I am not able to set percetnage format for those cells:

```
        Cell cell = OpenXmlHelper.GetCell(ws, address);            
        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = InsertCellInWorksheet(ws, rowIndex, column);
        }

        cell.DataType = CellValues.Number; 


        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value.ToString());
```

Instead of `cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;`  I need some code that sets `Percentage`. 
Can you give me some clues or tutorial on formatting percentage for excel cells in openxml?

Compared to [Open Xml Excel set cell format to be Percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129220/open-xml-excel-set-cell-format-to-be-percentage)
I have number 0.08 and I need to show it as 8%.

Answer (score -2):

Try `cell.StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U;`

Edit in response to renathy's comment

This code was adapted from the code provided by the Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool. When viewing a percentage formatted cell in this tool the code it generates is:

```
// Creates an Cell instance and adds its children.
public Cell GenerateCell()
{
    Cell cell1 = new Cell(){ CellReference = "A1", StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U };
    CellValue cellValue1 = new CellValue();
    cellValue1.Text = "0.2";

    cell1.Append(cellValue1);
    return cell1;
}
```

As to what the `1U` is, it appears to be the magic number that Microsoft decided to use to represent styles (the  U part just means that the number is unsigned).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @RahulSharma setting that property should format the cell as a percentage how is that not an answer?

Comment: You could add the above point as a comment as it simply add one liner reply. My intentions with the comment were not to disapprove your reply as an answer rather to add it as a comment to original question.

Comment: @RahulSharma I have to disagree, it is an answer even though it is a one liner and it should be posted as such so that the question can be marked as answered if it solves the problem.

Comment: This doesn't work. It doesn't change format of the cell. And even if it would be the correct answer, it would be good to see some comments - what is 1U for example.